# Getting a terminal error in Atom.io

Tags: atom-editor

I am getting a error in the terminal when I am running the 'Gem Dependencies'.

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

[This the terminal error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yM2J.png)

Thanks.

Comment: To help better you should give us more info, read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn what we like to know. To start you could also read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can't see how this is somehow Atom related

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$` in front of your console input:

```
gem install compass modular-scale sass
```

If the error is not created by you typing this command into the PowerShell, you should contact the Atom crew.

Comment: Still giving me the error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I edited my command-line input (removed the space between "modular- scale"). Try again please ;)

Comment: Can you give me the error you get after putting my most recent code into your console?